# Customizing bootstrap components for Glyphicons only

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When customizing bootstrap components. There are a lot of options to select. If I only want the glyphicons. Do I select these

1. Components - All uncheck except typography? what about Responsive utilities?
2. Glyphicons - only Glyphicons?
   3 JavaScript components - Any or None?

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable everything except for the Components -> Glyphicons If you only need glyphicons.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try that out.. as the CSS in others seems to be overriding all the other CSS elements and figuring out the CSS inheritance is mind boggling.

Comment: Using this and still not displaying. <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Envelope 
        </button>

Comment: do you have fonts folder with all the glyphicons included in the project?